# AddRastersToMosaicDataset_management performs slow

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-server, enterprise-geodatabase, performance

I have an enterprise Geodatabase (SQL Server) on my ArcGIS server machine. I perform my computations on several rasters on another machine (80 *.tif s with mean size of 50kb). When I want to add the result rasters to a mosaic dataset on my ArcGIS server machine using python, it performs very slowly and I have to wait for about 20 minutes.

```
for filename in glob.iglob('*.tif'):
    raster_name = 'Rater-' + raster_num +'.tif'
    arcpy.AddRastersToMosaicDataset_management('D:/example.sde/SampleMosaicDataset', "raster dataset", 'D:/GRIDS/' + filename)
```

How can I do this task with more speed?

Comment: I would assume it does some automatic updates every time a new dataset is added. maybe you can disable that somewhere?

Comment: @bugmenot123 what is it automatically updating? Can you explain more?

Comment: You can update the environmental variables parallel processing to use different CPU percentages. Such as 100% would be all, and 50% half. By default I believe it's on 50%.